# How to change Control-Y behavior in Excel-VBA's IDE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Excel VBA's IDE registers a Control-y as "cut this line of code".

By contrast, redo-ing is accomplished by Alt-e, R.

Is there any way to change this behavior and make Control-y be the much more common redo?

(For more on the default behavior, here is a link: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/ctrl-y-in-vba-ide.2198613/)

Comment: Not really. Might be possible using some third party software to create a new hot key

Comment: `Application.Onkey` method will do this for the application, but I don't think it works for the editor..

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497347/is-there-a-way-to-disable-access-2007s-code-editors-ctrly-shortcut-key

Comment: @gibberish: What is wrong with the answer below?

Comment: I am looking for a cannonical/authoritative answer to whether ANYTHING is possible within the Excel/VBA object model. For example, there is an [Excel VBE Object Model](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/visual-basic-editor/extensibility-object-model.htm) and I am wondering if the VBE can be directly programmed to solve this problem? *(I am open to the authoritative answer that **you can't get there from here** - if that is indeed the authoritative answer)*

Comment: @gibberish: Nope, even an[add-in](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/visual-basic-editor/extensibility-creating-addin.htm) cannot intercept hotkeys.

Answer (score 3):

In response to the question of :

*I am wondering if the VBE can be directly programmed to solve this problem?*

The answer unfortunately is negative.
The only way to modify the behavior is by using
[add-ins](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/visual-basic-editor/extensibility-creating-addin.htm)
whose capabilities are summed up by Microsoft as :

> - A startup module to trap the opening and closing of the add-in.
> - Some code to add our menu items to the commandbars on opening and remove them when closing
> - For the VBE, a class mosule to handle the menu items "Click" events
> - Some code to perform your menu's actions.

Specifically, intercepting hotkeys is not in the list.

The answer by Eliyahu is then still correct, and AutoHotKey (or AutoIt)
is still the only solution.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc - I'm glad you returned to add this as an answer as it answered my query.

Answer (score 2):

This [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script I wrote seems to work:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk

^y::
Send {escape}
Send !e;
Send r
Send {escape}
Send {escape}
return

#IfWinActive
```

Comment: It works for me, but I see a flashing contextual menu appearing for a fraction of second or so when I press CTRL+Y... Is this the expected behaviour? Can I avoid it somehow?

Comment: @Pere The script replicates "Alt-e, r" so I don't think it can be avoided

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after inppecting the code and learning how Autohotkey works. Thanks for explaining, @Eliyahu

Comment: @Eliyahu where do you put this script please ??? 

I would also like re-map Ctrl_Y to ShiftCtrl_X where it should have been in the 1st place :-/

Though it's great that Ctrl_Z or Ctrl_V undoes it, it still wrecks the undo stack

Comment: @Piecevcake You put it in a text file, which you then rename as an ahk file. Then if you have the autohotkey program running you can run the ahk file and it will be running in the background. I set the script to run automatically whenever I reboot by putting it in my Startup folder.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who don't want to see the menu flash using AutoHotkey. You can perform a control click on the redo button. (Yes I know, coordinates. But that's just how it is with Microsoft. Besides if you haven't rearranged the controls the following numbers should work fine. Oh and also for those who are unfamiliar with AutoHotkey, rest assured that it does not move your mouse.)

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk
^y::
ControlClick, x236 y67, A
return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Works well, but note that your coordinates only work if the Standard toolbar (with the Redo button) is directly underneath the Menu Bar (with File, Edit View...), and on the left, which isn't necessarily the case for everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Excel VBA's IDE registers a Control-y as "cut this line of code".

By contrast, redo-ing is accomplished by Alt-e, R.